# django POST in 2 models / database tables

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am absolutly new to this and just finished the tutorials into my needs. Now I'm stuck because I want to **save all data from POST orders in 2 models** at same time. I tried this `def create(self, valiated_data):` but the `Altkunde` Table is still empty, while I got lots of new entries in `Kunde` model.

After hours of research I can't find a solution.

Please give any hints or tips.

Here's my **models.py**

```
class Kunde(models.Model):
   QR = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='', primary_key=True)
   created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now_add=True)
   Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
   Info = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
   owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='kunden', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)


class AltKunde(models.Model):
   QR = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='', primary_key=True)
   created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now_add=True)
   Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
   Info = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, default='')
   Verleiher = models.OneToOneField(User, 'username')

   class Meta:
      ordering = ('created',)
```

**views.py**

```
class KundeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Kunde.objects.all()
    serializer_class = KundeSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)


class AltKundeView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = AltKunde.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AltkundeSerializer
```

**serializer.py**

```
class KundeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Kunde   #Kunden die Notebook leihen
        fields = ('url', 'QR', 'owner', 'created', 'Name', 'Info')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        Altkundeeintrag = AltKunde.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return Kunde.objects.create(**validated_data)

class AltkundeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AltKunde   #Kunden die Notebook geliehen haben (Altbestand)
        fields = ('url', 'QR', 'Verleiher' 'created', 'Name', 'Info')
```

Comment: could you please put `views.py` and `models.py` here, not link.

Comment: Okay, I inserted the whole code. :)

Comment: You could use a save signal on `Kunde` to save an `AltKunde` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/

Comment: I tried the signals but it seems I can't get the code structure right. There is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

In your `models.py`you could do this:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Kunde(AbstractKunde):
    ...

class AltKunde(AbstractKunde):
    ...

@receiver(post_save, sender=Kunde)
def handle_Kunde_created(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    //kwargs['created'] will return True if a Kunde instance is created.
    if not kwargs.get('created'):
        // I'm not doing anything here, but potentially
        // you can sync object updates here as well
        return

    AltKunde.objects.create(
        QR=instance.QR,
        created=instance.created,
        Name=instance.Name,
        Info=instance.Info,
        Verleiher=instance.Verleiher)
```

And in your KundeSerializer, you don't have to do this anymore: `Altkundeeintrag = AltKunde.objects.create(**validated_data)`